# uninstall packages using dpkg

Tags: package-management, uninstall, dpkg

I want to uninstall openoffice package and want to do this using single command or regular expression i.e

```
dpkg -r openoffice-org*
```

but dpkg doesnot accept wild cards

how can i uninstall all the packages using wildcard

Comment: The wild-card should work. Check whether you are typing `openoffice.org` or `openoffice-org`. Still, you would have to type the names of other packages, e.g. `uno-libs3`, `ure`

Comment: It doesnot work I have tried to remove evolution using 

    `sudo dpkg -P evolution*`

dpkg warning: ignoring request to remove evolution* which isn't installed

Comment: Did you test with `dpkg -r 'openoffice.org*'`? or even `dpkg -r openoffice.org\*`?  _"also replaced '-' with '.' "_

Answer (score 4):

One-liner to delete multiple packages with `dpkg` by wildcard:

```
dpkg --list|grep openoffice|awk '{ print $2 }'|xargs sudo dpkg -r
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually dpkg does not support wildcards
So if you need that feature you need this

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep "open-office" >list.txt
```

this file contains package and status you need to parse it and then feed to dpkg

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
sudo apt-get purge openoffice.org-base-core openoffice.org-common openoffice.org-core openoffice.org-style-human uno-libs3 ure openoffice.org-thesaurus-en-au openoffice.org-thesaurus-en-us openoffice.org-hyphenation openoffice.org-hyphenation-en-us openoffice.org-l10n-common
```

to purge the packages.

Running the wildcard will remove following too:

> aspell* aspell-en* dictionaries-common* hunspell-en-ca* hunspell-en-us* language-support-en* language-support-writing-en* myspell-en-au* myspell-en-gb* myspell-en-za* openoffice.org-base-core* openoffice.org-calc* openoffice.org-common* openoffice.org-core* openoffice.org-draw* openoffice.org-emailmerge* openoffice.org-gnome* openoffice.org-gtk* openoffice.org-help-en-us* openoffice.org-impress* openoffice.org-math* openoffice.org-style-human* openoffice.org-writer* python-uno* wbritish*

Using above is the safe way.

Comment: I tried apt-get but when I tried that it tries to connect to internet and also install other packages , but i want to perform this where there is no internet connection. Also I can remove openoffice packages using dpkg -P package1 package2 package3 , but I want to remove packages without having to type all the package names

Comment: dpkg doesn't support wildcards. So you'll have to do so. Or copy my list.

Comment: @FrederikSpang Why `dpkg` not support wild cards ^^? do you have any proof or reason?

Comment: apt-get will try to access internet only when you use apt-get install or apt-get update , etc but apt-get remove --purge doesnt need internet access

Comment: Not even for `apt-get install` internet is obsessive - local mirror e.g.